# App works only for but not for other users

Tags: authentication, heroku

I am editing the default app provided by the heroku. This works with my login. But other users doesn't see app working. My app requires permission - user_relationships, friends_relationships.

When I debug the access_token seen by the user, it correctly specifies the above permissions.

Somebody can please point me what is the issue?? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

// Provides access to app specific values such as your app id and app secret.
// Defined in 'AppInfo.php'
require_once('AppInfo.php');

// Enforce https on production
if (substr(AppInfo::getUrl(), 0, 8) != 'https://' && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1') {
header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit();
}

// This provides access to helper functions defined in 'utils.php'
require_once('utils.php');


 /****************************************************************************
 *
 * The content below provides examples of how to fetch Facebook data using the
* Graph API and FQL.  It uses the helper functions defined in 'utils.php' to
* do so.  You should change this section so that it prepares all of the
* information that you want to display to the user.
*
 ****************************************************************************/

 require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

// Instantiating Facebook object to access SDK
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
));

// Returns facebook user id of the current user
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id) {
try {
  // Fetch the viewer's basic information
  $basic = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
// If the call fails we check if we still have a user. The user will be
// cleared if the error is because of an invalid accesstoken
if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
  header('Location: '. AppInfo::getUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
  exit();
}
}

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $access_token;
// Here is an example of a FQL call that fetches all of your friends that are
// using this app
$app_using_friends = $facebook->api(array(
 'method' => 'fql.query',
 'query' => 'SELECT uid, name, relationship_status FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2  FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'
));

}

// Fetch the basic info of the app that they are using
$app_info = $facebook->api('/'. AppInfo::appID());

$app_name = idx($app_info, 'name', '');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes" />

<title><?php echo he($app_name); ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/screen.css" media="Screen" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/mobile.css" media="handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" type="text/css" />

<!--[if IEMobile]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen" type="text/css"  />
<![endif]-->

<!-- These are Open Graph tags.  They add meta data to your  -->
<!-- site that facebook uses when your content is shared     -->
<!-- over facebook.  You should fill these tags in with      -->
<!-- your data.  To learn more about Open Graph, visit       -->
<!-- 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/'       -->
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo he($app_name); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl('/logo.png'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo he($app_name); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My first app" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function logResponse(response) {
    if (console && console.log) {
      console.log('The response was', response);
    }
  }

  $(function(){
    // Set up so we handle click on the buttons
    $('#postToWall').click(function() {
      FB.ui(
        {
          method : 'feed',
          link   : $(this).attr('data-url')
        },
        function (response) {
          // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
          if (response != null) {
            logResponse(response);
          }
        }
      );
    });

    $('#sendToFriends').click(function() {
      FB.ui(
        {
          method : 'send',
          link   : $(this).attr('data-url')
        },
        function (response) {
          // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
          if (response != null) {
            logResponse(response);
          }
        }
      );
    });

    $('#sendRequest').click(function() {
      FB.ui(
        {
          method  : 'apprequests',
          message : $(this).attr('data-message')
        },
        function (response) {
          // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
          if (response != null) {
            logResponse(response);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  });
</script>

<!--[if IE]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var tags = ['header', 'section'];
    while(tags.length)
      document.createElement(tags.pop());
  </script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/channel.html', // Channel File
  //oauth        : true,
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true // parse XFBML
    });

//FB.login({
    //      scope   : 'user_relationships,friends_relationships'
   //   });

    // Listen to the auth.login which will be called when the user logs in
    // using the Login button
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      // We want to reload the page now so PHP can read the cookie that the
      // Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
      // window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
      // post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
      // user asking if they want to send data again.
      window.location = window.location;
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

   <header class="clearfix">
   <?php if (isset($basic)) { ?>
   <p id="picture" style="background-image: url(https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo he($user_id); ?>/picture?type=normal)"></p>

   <div>
    <h1>Welcome, <strong><?php echo he(idx($basic, 'name')); ?></strong></h1>
    <p class="tagline">
      This is my app. My First Facebook app. 
      <a href="<?php echo he(idx($app_info, 'link'));?>" target="_top"><?php echo he($app_name); ?></a>
    </p>

    <div id="share-app">
   </div>
   <?php } else { ?>
   <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="fb-login-button"       data-scope="user_likes,user_photos,user_relationships,friends_relationships"></div>
   </div>
   <?php } ?>
  </header>

  <?php
  if ($user_id) {
  ?>

var $shaheeds = 0;
var $aazaads  = 0;
var $confused = 0;
var $in_trap  = 0;
var $total    = 0;

  <section id="samples" class="clearfix">
  <h1>Examples of the Facebook Graph API</h1>

  <div class="list">
    <h3>Shaheed Friends</h3>
    <ul class="shaheed">
      <?php
        foreach ($app_using_friends as $friend) {
          // Extract the pieces of info we need from the requests above
          $id = idx($friend, 'uid');
          $name = idx($friend, 'name');
      $r_status = idx($friend, 'relationship_status');
      if($r_status == "Married"){
          $shaheeds++;
      ?>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo he($id); ?>" target="_top">
          <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo he($id) ?>/picture?type=square" alt="<?php echo he($id); ?>">
          <?php echo he($name); ?>
        </a>
      </li>
      <?php
      }
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="list inline">
    <h3>Recent photos</h3>
    <ul class="photos">
      <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
          // Extract the pieces of info we need from the requests above
          $id = idx($photo, 'id');
          $picture = idx($photo, 'picture');
          $link = idx($photo, 'link');

          $class = ($i++ % 4 === 0) ? 'first-column' : '';
      ?>
      <li style="background-image: url(<?php echo he($picture); ?>);" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo he($link); ?>" target="_top"></a>
      </li>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="list">
    <h3>Friends In Trap</h3>
    <ul class="in-trap">
      <?php
        foreach ($app_using_friends as $friend) {
          // Extract the pieces of info we need from the requests above
          $id = idx($friend, 'uid');
          $name = idx($friend, 'name');
      $r_status = idx($friend, 'relationship_status');
      if($r_status == "Engaged" || $r_status == "In a relationship"){
          // This display's the object that the user liked as a link to
          // that object's page.
    $in_trap++;
      ?>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo he($id); ?>" target="_top">
          <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo he($id) ?>/picture?type=square" alt="<?php echo he($name); ?>">
          <?php echo he($name); ?>
        </a>
      </li>
      <?php
      }
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="list">
    <h3>Azaad Friends</h3>
    <ul class="friends">
      <?php
        foreach ($app_using_friends as $auf) {
          // Extract the pieces of info we need from the requests above
          $id = idx($auf, 'uid');
          $name = idx($auf, 'name');
      $r_status = idx($auf, 'relationship_status');
      if($r_status == "Single"){
          $aazaads++;
      ?>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo he($id); ?>" target="_top">
          <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo he($id) ?>/picture?type=square" alt="<?php echo he($name); ?>">
          <?php echo he($name); ?>
        </a>
      </li>
      <?php
      }
      $total++;
        }
    $confused = $total - $aazaads - $shaheeds - $in_trap;
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </section>
<section id="graphs" class="clearfix">
<h1>"Graph"</h1>
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:<?php echo he($shaheeds)?>,<?php echo he($aazaads)?>,<?php echo he($in_trap)?>,<?php echo he($confused)?>&chs=250x100&chl=Shaheed|Aazaad|In Trap|Unknown" />
</section>

  <?php
  }
  ?>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem. for this one thing is sure we have to disable `sandbox` mode. for that you must go to facebook developers app. And in that advanced. But i am facing the problem. because to disable `sandbox` mode we have to provide privacy policy url and secure canvas page url.